# Neo4j python driver results don't contain edge data

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4j-python-driver

This is my Cypher query and its equivalent result in neo4j Browser

> MATCH (a)-[b:REFERENCE]->(c) RETURN a,b,c LIMIT 200

[image]

The b column (or key in JSON) contains the relationship and all the data that is associated with it. This is my ideal response.

However running the same query in my Python API using the neo4j driver(==5.7.0) gives me the following result

[image]

The 'b' column now gives me redundant and incomplete information

Following is a snippet of the API code

```
with self.driver.session() as session:
    return [record.data() for record in session.run(query)]
```

**What I tried:**

1. Using different methods for Record object as seen [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/api.html#record)
2. Using different methods for Response object as seen [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/api.html#result)
3. Changing query to

   > MATCH p = ()-[:REFERENCE]->() RETURN p LIMIT 200

None of this yielded different results

Answer (score 0):

*The relationship type is different between your 2 results (`REFERENCE` vs `AUTHORED`). But it probably does not matter with respect to my answer.*

In the Browser response, the `b` data is just telling you that the relationship contains no properties, starts at `a`, and ends at `c`.

Your Python response is essentially saying the same thing. So you are not missing any information.